# Are these inequalities useless for getting better estimates? If not what is needed?

Tags: inequality, soft-question, intuition

Are these inequalities useless for getting better estimates? If not what is needed? My motivation for asking this question is to get a glimpse to the mind of masters that can tell if a line of reasoning looks like to be useful or should be abandoned and alternative path should be taken ( just by intuitionistic reasoning that would seem reasonable without having to be correct).

Background:
While working on [this questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402304/what-would-gauss-do-in-this-case-adding-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-dots-fra), found out some inequities. The motivation was to find some inequalities and squeeze them for better approximation, what I got didn't seem to get me any closer to anything useful.

My question is: could some inequity masters to show that these results can be used to get somewhere closer to answer or , loosely explain loosely why these inequalities are not on the right track anywhere closer to a better approximation?

$\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} > \frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{4} = \frac {1}{2}$

$\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{5} + \frac {1}{6}+\frac {1}{7} > \frac {1}{8}+\frac {1}{8} + \frac {1}{8}+\frac {1}{8} = \frac {1}{2}$

In general : 
$ \frac{1}{2} < \sum _{2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{k} $

or more generally :
$ \frac{1}{\alpha} < \sum _{\alpha^n}^{\alpha^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{k} $

also

$$  \sum _{\alpha^n}^{\alpha^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{\alpha} < \sum _{{(\alpha+1)}^n}^{{(\alpha+1)}^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{\alpha+1}$$

Some trivial inequalities I tried to use:

$2^6<100<2^7$,

$3^4<100<3^5$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by
"useless for getting better estimates",
but your inequalities
are quite useful as they are.

First,
they enable you to prove
that the harmonic sum
$H_n
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}
$
diverges as
$n \to \infty$,
and gives a reasonable estimate
for the growth of this sum.

Second,
your estimate forms the basis
for the Cauchy condensation test
for whether or not a series converges.
Look it up.

All in all,
if you discovered this by yourself,
I am impressed.

Comment: I had seen the original idea for the proof of divergence (the first 2 inequalities), I have no original thought here just like a juxtaposition monkey randomly trying different different things to see if can sandwich the harmonic series between two other estimateable series and then squeeze them. By no means I am trying to find a better estimate than $\ln n$ for estimation of harmonic series

Comment: @Arjang Why not? For instance, $\log(2n+1)$ is closer to $H_n$ than $\log(n)$ is. Asymptotically, $\log(2)-\gamma$ < $\gamma$.